# why can't blender read a movie which blender has itself rendered?

Tags: import, video

please excuse my ignorance. i'm starting to use blender 2.72 for its Video Editor.
i'm slowly making progress, but ran into a problem
when i tried to re-import a rendered movie.
blender seems to think it has no dimensions...could that be the problem?
to be clear - i rendered an animation (movie)as avi, from a Blender Session, and then imported it again, into the same session, as a fresh source file for further processing. but the sequencer doesn't read it....
i tried various rendering output options, but none seem to correct this.

thanks, Roland

Answer (score 1):

okay i figured out the problem.  must make sure proxy view preferences match proxies which have been built or re-built.  i hadn't built the 50 percent proxy but was viewing that proxy in the viewer.....hence the lack of result.